# 2d Array track player movement into specific spaces around an entity

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Ok, so I need assistance with an array, I have a 2D array that a player can move through, at the moment I'm randomly generating an entity and a player is supposed to be able to interact with it. I have one decently long if statement that tracks if the player approaches the entity however unable to increase the range at what will trigger a prompt. This if statement is long and was frustrating to wrap my head around at times but is as follows;

```
if(((getPlayerX() == getEntityX() - getPlayerRange()) || (getPlayerX() == getEntityX() + getPlayerRange()) || (getPlayerX() == getEntityX())) && ((getPlayerY() == getEntityY() - getPlayerRange()) || (getPlayerY() == getEntityY() + getPlayerRange()) || (getPlayerY() == getEntityY()))){
```

However when the range increase to two (from its default which is one), this no longer works. I want to implement this so a player with higher range can still interact with this entity. Is there an easier way to do this that might be more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
int xDistance = Math.abs(getPlayerX() - getEntityX());
int yDistance = Math.abs(getPlayerY() - getEntityY());

if (xDistance <= getPlayerRange() && yDistance <= getPlayerRange()){ ... }
```

Calculate absolute distance and then compare with player range.

Even tho it's more code than your current version, it is more readable even for range of 1 in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah this works well, thanks a ton dude, been stuck on this for a while now, sorry for the late response, only just implemented it